# How to destroy RotateAnimation object?

Tags: android

Once this code is called:

```
Animation newAnimation = new RotateAnimation( recordedOffsetOrientation, offsetedOrientation, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

how can I destroy that object?

I found that calling `setVisibility(View.GONE);` on ImageView on which is applied RotateAnimation is impossible. So that mean I need to destroy this object before I try to hide it, right? If yes, how to do that?

I tried with  `newAnimation.reset();` and `newAnimation = null;` and first option gives me an error (app crush) and second option does not solve the problem.

I also tried to search for an answer here and on android development documentation and did not succeed to find it.

Comment: im not really sure about this but you can try
    newAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    newAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);

Comment: @Snicolas Nope that gives the same error as newAnimation.reset();

Comment: @NoobMe Actually I already have those two lines at my code.

Comment: why is setVisibility impossible? any error about that?

Comment: App does not gives any errors at all with setVisibility function. It just won't to hide element, seems like it is ignoring setVisibility. However, that part of code worked perfectly before i started to use RotateAnimation function.